# C# String EndsWith Returning True Issue

Tags: c#, ends-with

I'm opening a file using the OpenFile Dialog and I want to confirm that the file is in an excel format.

The file that I opened is "C:\Desktop\Distribution.xls", but both criteria of my if statement are evaluating to true.  Is there another method that I should be using?

```
          DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (result==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            file = file.Trim();

            if (!file.EndsWith(".xlsx")||!file.EndsWith(".xls"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect file format.  Please save file in an .xls format");
            }

            else
            {
                book = application.Workbooks.Open(file);
                sheet = (Worksheet)book.Worksheets[1];
                range = sheet.get_Range("A1", "A1".ToString());

                range.EntireRow.Delete(XlDirection.xlUp);

                sheet.Cells[1, 2].EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@";

                book.SaveAs(csvConverstion, XlFileFormat.xlCSV);
                book.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                application.Quit();

            }
```

Comment: Doesnt explain the issue but you should use `System.IO.Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName)!=".xls"`

Comment: "myExcelFile.xls" -> `!File.EndsWith(".xlsx")` is true, `!File.EndsWith(".xls")` is false, `true || false` is true.

Comment: In addition to what everyone has said, you might find the [`FileDialog.Filter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter(v=vs.110).aspx) property useful.

Comment: Using `||` operator: `true || true == true`, `true || false == true`, `false || true == true`, `false || false == false`. Using `&&` operator: `true && true == true`, `true && false == false`, `false && true == false`, `false && false == false`. So you're getting the `MessageBox.Show` method because `false || true == true`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be used "&&" instead of "||"

The If statement **Can't** ever be false because you're trying to evaluate that it ends with two different strings at the same time (which is impossible).

You *want* to say, "If file does not end in .xlsx **and** it also doesn't end with .xls, it is invalid"

Replace this:

```
if (!file.EndsWith(".xlsx")||!file.EndsWith(".xls"))
```

With:

```
if (!file.EndsWith(".xlsx") && !file.EndsWith(".xls"))
```

#### Alternative Solutions:

Use a better-reading structure, without a negative "IF", such as:

```
if (file.EndsWith(".xlsx") || file.EndsWith(".xls"))
{
    //Do stuff
}
else
{
     //Invalid
}
```

**Or, as suggested in the comments:**

```
string ext = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
if(ext.Equals(".xls") || ext.Equals(".xlsx"))
{
    // Do stuff
}
else
{
    // Invalid
}
```

Comment: Good catch. But he should use `Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName)!=".xls"` instead.

Comment: @TimSchmelter OP is using `.xls` and `.xslx` extensions, not just `.xls`

Comment: @IvanGarcíaTopete: sure. My comment was not meant to be a complete answer

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks. Added your comment and another alternative solution.

Comment: OP should also check for case-insensitivity as .xls and .XLS are valid Excel file extensions. So instead of the regular EndsWith and Equals use the one which accepts StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase.

Answer (score 2):

The condition `!file.EndsWith(".xlsx") || !file.EndsWith(".xls")` can not ever return true. Because the file name can not ends both with `.xlsx` and `.xls`.

The correct condition is with "and" operator: `!file.EndsWith(".xlsx") && !file.EndsWith(".xls")`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid negatives in if statements. If you switch the blocks around, you can do a test to see if the filename is valid like this

```
    if (file.EndsWith(".xlsx")||file.EndsWith(".xls"))
    {
        book = application.Workbooks.Open(file);
        sheet = (Worksheet)book.Worksheets[1];
        range = sheet.get_Range("A1", "A1".ToString());

        range.EntireRow.Delete(XlDirection.xlUp);

        sheet.Cells[1, 2].EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@";

        book.SaveAs(csvConverstion, XlFileFormat.xlCSV);
        book.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        application.Quit();

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect file format.  Please save file in an .xls format");
    }
```

It's much more readable and easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Just another improvement which is too long for a comment. If you want to check extensions use `System.IO.Path.GetExtension`. You can store the valid extensions in a collection. Also consider that an extension could be `.XLS` which is valid but not with your code.

```
string[] validExt = {".xls",".xlsx"};
string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
bool fileValid = validExt.Contains(extension, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
if(!fileValid)
{
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what everyone has said, you might find the [`FileDialog.Filter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter(v=vs.110).aspx) property useful.

You can use it to restrict the allowed extensions like this:

```
openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel workbooks(*.xls;*.xlsx)|*.xls;*.xlsx";
```

That will only show files with ".xls" and ".xlsx" extensions, leaving the user with no choice but to select files with the right extensions.

Also, if you decided to validate the file extension, you should use case-insensitive comparison because it's very common to find paths with uppercase extensions (e.g., "SomeName.XLSX"). You can do that using the [`String.Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file);
if (!string.Equals(ext, ".xls", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
    !string.Equals(ext, ".xlsx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    //...
}
```

Note that even if you used `FileDialog.Filter`, you might still need to confirm that the selected file has the right extension in the [`FileDialog.FileOk`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.fileok(v=vs.110).aspx) event because OpenFileDialog could allow selecting shortcuts that refer to files with different extensions even though the allowed extensions are restricted by the `Filter` property.